# Error in converting org file to md file: Unknown "nil" back-end: Aborting export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, markdown

I'm trying to export simple org file to md format using command below:

```
emacs --batch myLanes.org --eval "(progn (require 'org) (org-export-as 'md))" > myLanes.md
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Unknown "nil" back-end: Aborting export
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: You will need to require `ox-md` as well: it is not loaded by default.

Comment: @NickD, yes it's better, not throwing an error now but the output file is empty :-(

Comment: Don't use stdout redirection: the file is written by the exporter, not printed to stdout.

Comment: @NickD, And where the exported does the export? I don't know whether I have another bug or suddenly get blinded as I can't see anything produced in the calling folder.

Comment: Right: `org-export-as` is not the right interface for this - try `org-md-export-to-markdown`. If the input file is `myLanes.org`, the output file will be `myLanes.md` in the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Summarizing the back-and-forth in the comments]

Three problems:

- By default the `markdown` exporter is not loaded.
- The output of the export process can be a buffer or a file, but it is not the `stdout` of the Emacs process, so you cannot use output redirection.<sup>[1]</sup>
- `org-export-as` is the generic interface that returns the transcoded output as a string. Higher-level interfaces create the output buffer or file. In this case, `org-md-export-to-markdown` is the higher-level interface that produces a file.

In summary, the invocation is:

```shell
emacs --batch myLanes.org \
      --eval "(progn (require 'org) (require 'ox-md) (org-md-export-to-markdown))"
```

That produces a file `myLanes.md` in the same directory as the input file `myLanes.org` (in this case, the current working directory , but you *can* use pathnames).

---

*Footnote*:

[1] Well, you *can* but you have to do it yourself, e.g. with `(princ (org-export-as 'md))`.